# CFHTTP returns content from wrong URL

Tags: xml, coldfusion, rss, cfhttp

I recently moved some applications from a ColdFusion 8 server to a new machine running ColdFusion 10.

One of my scripts is showing some very strange behavior now.

I am using cfhttp to pull the contents from an RSS feed, but the "FileContent" I am getting back from cfhttp does not match the URL I am expecting.

I confirmed the URL I'm using is valid and the XML it provides passes validation tests. The following test code should get the XML from the RSS feed and display it on the screen. I have no idea where the content it actually returns is coming from.

```
<cfset theFeedURL = "http://www.thonline.com/search/?q=&t=article&l=50&d=&d1=8/20/2014&d2=8/21/2014&s=priority&sd=desc&c[]=sports/local_sports*&f=rss&cacheBreaker=9876">
<cfhttp url="#theFeedURL#" result="MyRSS" resolveurl="yes"></cfhttp>
<cfoutput>#MyRSS.FileContent#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The first thing to do here is fire up Wireshark and examine the raw traffic to verify that your code is hitting the correct URL (check the server IP address) and that you're getting back the wrong data. This will tell you where to look next.

Comment: I don't think the problem is local to my server. I ran this test code on a different website on a separate network and get the same results

Comment: You don't yet have proof that your system is requesting the correct URL.  Examine the raw traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers, but I solved this issue. The problem was in the URL I was using to get the feed.

If you look in the query string I'm using, I have a couple items that have slashes in them (the d1, d2, and c[] variables)

While I can paste that URL in a browser as-is and get what I want, cfhttp doesn't like it that way.
I needed to use `URLEncodedFormat()` to replace all of the slashes in the query string with %2F and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Ah, so the request was probably being redirected to the home page, or some other default page. Thanks for posting a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<cfdump var="#MyRSS#" />` to your code to view as much of the transaction as possible.

If the problem persists, check out the `getAsBinary='never'` attribute for CFHTTP.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfhttp

Comment: There was no mention of content type issues. He is saying that the content he is receiving appears to be for a *different* URL than the one he requested. ie Like requesting the Adobe home page and getting back the content for Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: When the result of the CFHTTP call is dumped, additional data ABOUT the call will be available: charSet, errorDetail, fileContent, header, mimeType, responseHeader, statusCode, text.

This may provide useful data to allow successful debugging of the issue described.

Comment: Of course. However, the above is a comment, not an answer. ([S.O. works differently than a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)). I realize you cannot [post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) yet, just FYI.